# Different page view across browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I am building a website and i have the following problem. In chrome everything is ok but in firefox the whole page is zoomed in around 20 %. That destroys the structure of the page. I have tested in many computers and it's everywhere the same.

[Here is a demo](http://branduniverse.dk/Build/index.html)

Try to open it with chrome first and then with firefox.

Comment: On mac, chrome and firefox look the same

Comment: On windows, both look the same to me too. My screen width is 1920px and I used the FF responsive design mode to shrink the site down to ~100px.

Comment: Please edit your question and paste your code, for further reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table of your body of page has 5 columns with width 15%, 15%, 40%, 15% and 15%.
In the first column you have an image with `width="200"`. If your screen resolution has lower than `200 * (100 / 15) = 1333` pixel at width, your page shrieked at two columns (first and fifth) and you get this result. The same was issued at the right column with word *iværksættersuccesoplevelser*.

Firefox ignore this image and word *iværksættersuccesoplevelser* and use your percentage values to show your page.

Comment: Apparently, this doesn't occur on Firefox for Mac (see Pedro's comment and my answer), is it a Windows-only behaviour?

Comment: @LarsBeck what is your screen resolution? Site looks fine at major browsers if you have a screen with resolution more than 1334x*.

Comment: I'm on a LED Cinema Display (2560 × 1440), but I resized the browser windows even to the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your website in all major browsers on Mac OS and everything looks fine. Apparently it's a problem with your Firefox only, did you try <kbd>Cmd</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to reset the zoom level? You may also have a look on [this](https://support.mozilla.org/de/questions/963009#answer-448757).